# Is it possible to add 3rd party or custom InkToolbar with InkCanvas in UWP XAML?

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml, inkcanvas

I'm working with UWP app. I need an `InkCanvas` with custom `inkToolbar`. I've already added the basic `inkToolbar` but that is not my requirement, I need more options than the basic one. Here is the image what I've achieved: [image: I've achieved]

But I need something like this: 
[image: I need something like this]

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

It is mentioned in [this article from msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/input/ink-toolbar) that you have two options when customizing `InkCanvas` output:

- Write custom code working with `InkPresenter` which is bound to `InkCanvas`
- Use default `InkToolbar`

You will have to write custom control for your toolbar and use first option (mentioned in the article).

Answer (score 0):

Here an custom toolbar on [Github](https://github.com/twytec/InkCanvasCustomToolbar)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In general, we prefer that users do not answer questions with only a link, instead explaining their solution within the answer.

Comment: Sorry, but my english is very bad